# How can I validate w2ui columns in a datatable?

Tags: datatables, w2ui

What event should I use to validate a value in a field within a datatable?
For instance, I need to ensure that a field is not null.  I know this error can be caught when data is sent to the server.  Can I catch the error and highlight the specific field before submitting my middleware?

I have tried to use the onEditField event.  This completes before entry of new value so the event has nothing to evaluate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `onChange` event.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6fvo7m42/)

```
$(function () {
    $('#grid').w2grid({ 
        name: 'grid', 
        columns: [                
            { field: 'fname', caption: 'First Name', size: '30%', editable: {type: 'text'} },
        ],
        records: [
          { recid: 1, fname: "Name1"},
          { recid: 2, fname: "Name2"}
        ],
        onChange : function(event){
          event.done(function(ev){
            console.log(ev);
          });
        }
    });    
});
```

From the [docs](http://w2ui.com/web/docs/1.5/w2grid.onChange):

> Called when user changes any field in the editable row.

In the example above, if you change `Name2` to `Name3`, the event object will contain:

```
{
  ...
  "value_new": "Name3",
  "value_previous": "Name2",
  "value_original": "Name2",
}
```

The event object will also contain further information, such as column and record index, so you can indeed highlight the cell / row based on the new value if you want to.

If you are using w2ui 1.4, use `event.onComplete = function(ev){...}` instead of `event.done(...)`.